# Intellij: running a spark-scala script in local hadoop with hive context

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

Could you help to resolve the error:

> input refs are invalid: /user/hive/warehouse/bkfs.db/asmt_02013.

I am new to the Intellij tool and trying to run a spark-scala application that connects to hive for metastore and data.

The project I am trying is TopNotch from GitHub. I was able to run it from a command prompt successfully. This uses `SQLContext` and looksup at the hive table and run the sqlcontext queries.

Now I am trying from the Intellij tool (installed with scala plugin and added spark lib). I was successful in running the test which looksup at the local derby metastore.

I am running in local mode with the below configuration:

```
Main class : com.bfm.topnotch.tnengine.TnEngine
VM options : -Dspark.master=local[4]
Program arguments: example/plan.json example/assertions.json
Working directory: /opt/TopNotch
```

And the program is not able to detect the hive warehouse. Is it not able to connect to local cluster. Is it anything I am missing at the configuration level?

Here's the log:

> Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
>       SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>       SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>       SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.5.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>       SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
>       SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
>       16/06/09 18:51:23 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.5.1
>       16/06/09 18:51:23 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>       16/06/09 18:51:23 WARN Utils: Your hostname, UBU-xxx resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.0.103 instead (on interface wlan0)
>       16/06/09 18:51:23 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
>       16/06/09 18:51:23 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: revathy
>       16/06/09 18:51:23 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: revathy
>       16/06/09 18:51:23 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(revathy); users with modify permissions: Set(revathy)
>       16/06/09 18:51:24 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
>       16/06/09 18:51:24 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
>       16/06/09 18:51:25 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.0.103:33690]
>       16/06/09 18:51:25 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 33690.
>       16/06/09 18:51:25 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
>       16/06/09 18:51:25 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
>       16/06/09 18:51:25 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-0d78f5e9-d456-4d37-8e12-1cdade2611d8
>       16/06/09 18:51:25 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 945.8 MB
>       16/06/09 18:51:25 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-20654ea0-bd13-4a23-9865-7ea80d7ec6cc/httpd-28c0ae2e-2c10-405f-b3d6-6237f3d409b0
>       16/06/09 18:51:25 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
>       16/06/09 18:51:25 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 44556.
>       16/06/09 18:51:25 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
>       16/06/09 18:51:25 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
>       16/06/09 18:51:26 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4041.
>       16/06/09 18:51:26 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.0.103:4041
>       16/06/09 18:51:26 WARN MetricsSystem: Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
>       16/06/09 18:51:26 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
>       16/06/09 18:51:26 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 52996.
>       16/06/09 18:51:26 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 52996
>       16/06/09 18:51:26 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
>       16/06/09 18:51:26 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:52996 with 945.8 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 52996)
>       16/06/09 18:51:26 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
>       16/06/09 18:51:27 INFO HiveContext: Initializing execution hive, version 1.2.1
>       16/06/09 18:51:27 INFO ClientWrapper: Inspected Hadoop version: 2.4.0
>       16/06/09 18:51:27 INFO ClientWrapper: Loaded org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop23Shims for Hadoop version 2.4.0
>       16/06/09 18:51:27 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
>       16/06/09 18:51:28 INFO ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
>       16/06/09 18:51:28 INFO Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
>       16/06/09 18:51:28 INFO Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
>       16/06/09 18:51:28 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
>       16/06/09 18:51:28 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
>       16/06/09 18:51:35 INFO ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
>       16/06/09 18:51:36 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
>       16/06/09 18:51:36 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
>       16/06/09 18:51:41 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
>       16/06/09 18:51:41 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
>       16/06/09 18:51:42 INFO MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
>       16/06/09 18:51:42 INFO ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
>       16/06/09 18:51:42 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
>       16/06/09 18:51:43 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
>       16/06/09 18:51:43 INFO HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
>       16/06/09 18:51:43 INFO HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
>       16/06/09 18:51:44 INFO HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
>       16/06/09 18:51:44 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_all_databases
>       16/06/09 18:51:44 INFO audit: ugi=revathy   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_all_databases
>       16/06/09 18:51:44 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_functions: db=default pat=
>
>       *16/06/09 18:51:44 INFO audit: ugi=revathy   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_functions: db=default pat=* 
>       16/06/09 18:51:44 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MResourceUri" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
>       16/06/09 18:51:45 INFO SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/ffc54942-5591-4a60-bb33-02322eef4bf8_resources
>       16/06/09 18:51:45 INFO SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/revathy/ffc54942-5591-4a60-bb33-02322eef4bf8
>       16/06/09 18:51:45 INFO SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/revathy/ffc54942-5591-4a60-bb33-02322eef4bf8
>       16/06/09 18:51:45 INFO SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/revathy/ffc54942-5591-4a60-bb33-02322eef4bf8/_tmp_space.db
>       16/06/09 18:51:45 INFO HiveContext: default warehouse location is /user/hive/warehouse
>       16/06/09 18:51:45 INFO HiveContext: Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 1.2.1 using Spark classes.
>       16/06/09 18:51:45 INFO ClientWrapper: Inspected Hadoop version: 2.4.0
>       16/06/09 18:51:45 INFO ClientWrapper: Loaded org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop23Shims for Hadoop version 2.4.0
>       16/06/09 18:51:45 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>       16/06/09 18:51:45 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
>       16/06/09 18:51:45 INFO ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
>       16/06/09 18:51:45 INFO Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
>       16/06/09 18:51:45 INFO Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
>       16/06/09 18:51:46 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
>       16/06/09 18:51:46 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
>       16/06/09 18:51:47 INFO ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
>       16/06/09 18:51:48 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
>       16/06/09 18:51:48 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
>       16/06/09 18:51:48 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
>       16/06/09 18:51:48 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
>       16/06/09 18:51:48 INFO Query: Reading in results for query "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.SQLQuery@0" since the connection used is closing
>       16/06/09 18:51:48 INFO MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
>       16/06/09 18:51:48 INFO ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
>       16/06/09 18:51:48 INFO HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
>       16/06/09 18:51:48 INFO HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
>       16/06/09 18:51:48 INFO HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
>       16/06/09 18:51:48 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_all_databases
>       16/06/09 18:51:48 INFO audit: ugi=revathy   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_all_databases
>       16/06/09 18:51:48 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_functions: db=default pat=
>
>       *16/06/09 18:51:48 INFO audit: ugi=revathy   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_functions: db=default pat=*
>  
>       16/06/09 18:51:48 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MResourceUri" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
>       16/06/09 18:51:49 INFO SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/167b5668-dab0-4dce-bff1-1bfc833b7166_resources
>       16/06/09 18:51:49 INFO SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/revathy/167b5668-dab0-4dce-bff1-1bfc833b7166
>       16/06/09 18:51:49 INFO SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/revathy/167b5668-dab0-4dce-bff1-1bfc833b7166
>       16/06/09 18:51:49 INFO SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/revathy/167b5668-dab0-4dce-bff1-1bfc833b7166/_tmp_space.db
>       16/06/09 18:51:49 INFO TnEngine: parsing configurations
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There was an error with the command in position 0. The message was: The following input refs are invalid: /user/hive/warehouse/bkfs.db/asmt_02013
>           at com.bfm.topnotch.tnengine.TnEngine.run(TnEngine.scala:59)
>           at com.bfm.topnotch.tnengine.TnEngine$.main(TnEngine.scala:34)
>           at com.bfm.topnotch.tnengine.TnEngine.main(TnEngine.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Comment: Is this problem fixed?. I am too getting this error. Please post the solution if found. ta

Comment: Hi Srinivas, It got resolved. We will have to explicity specify the hive datawarehouse location. Let me know if you have still problem, I can paste the code